# print the last letter of each word to make a string using `awk` command

Tags: regex, awk, substr

I have this line

```
UDACBG UYAZAM DJSUBU WJKMBC NTCGCH DIDEVO RHWDAS
```

i am trying to print the last letter of each word to make a string using `awk` command

```
awk '{ print substr($1,6) substr($2,6) substr($3,6) substr($4,6) substr($5,6) substr($6,6) }'
```

In case I don't know how many characters a word contains, what is the correct command to print the last character of $column, and instead of the repeding `substr` command, how can I use it only once to print specific characters in different columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have just this one single line to handle you can use

```sh
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) r = r "" substr($i,length($i))} END{print r}' file
```

If you have multiple lines in the input:

```sh
awk '{r=""; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) r = r "" substr($i,length($i)); print r}' file
```

*Details*:

- `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) r = r "" substr($i,length($i))` - iterate over all fields in the current record, `i` is the field ID, `$i` is the field value, and all last chars of each field (retrieved with `substr($i,length($i))`) are appended to `r` variable
- `END{print r}` prints the `r` variable once `awk` script finishes processing.
- In the second solution, `r` value is cleared upon each line processing start, and its value is printed after processing all fields in the current record.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/4lJUQc):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='UDACBG UYAZAM DJSUBU WJKMBC NTCGCH DIDEVO RHWDAS'
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) r = r "" substr($i,length($1))} END{print r}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
GMUCHOS
```

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk and `gensub`:

```
$ gawk '{print gensub(/([^ ]+)([^ ])( |$)/,"\\2","g")}' file
```

Output:

```
GMUCHOS
```

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** With GNU `awk` you could try following `awk` program, written and tested eith shown samples.

```
awk -v RS='.([[:space:]]+|$)' 'RT{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",RT);val=val RT} END{print val}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Set record separator as any character followed by space OR end of value/line. Then as per OP's requirement remove unnecessary newline/spaces from fetched value; keep on creating val which has matched value of RS, finally when `awk` program is done with reading whole Input_file print the value of variable then.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using record separator as null and using `match` function on values to match regex `(.[[:space:]]+)|(.$)` to get last letter values only with each match found, keep adding matched values into a variable and at last in END block of `awk` program print variable's value.

```
awk -v RS= '
{
  while(match($0,/(.[[:space:]]+)|(.$)/)){
    val=val substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
END{
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple substitutions on individual lines is the job sed exists to do:

```
$ sed 's/[^ ]*\([^ ]\) */\1/g' file
GMUCHOS
```

Answer (score 2):

using many tools

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <file | rev | cut -c1 | paste -sd'\0'

GMUCHOS
```

separate the words to lines, reverse so that we can pick the first char easily, and finally paste them back together without a delimiter.  Not the shortest solution but I think the most trivial one...

Comment: On OS X, `tr -s ' ' '\n' <file | rev | cut -c1 | paste -sd'\0' -`

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this as follows, let `file.txt` content be

```
UDACBG UYAZAM DJSUBU WJKMBC NTCGCH DIDEVO RHWDAS
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[[:alpha:]]\\>";OFS=""}{$1=$1;print}' file.txt
```

output

```
GMUCHOS
```

Explanation: Inform AWK to treat any alphabetic character at end of word and use empty string as output field seperator. `$1=$1` is used to trigger line rebuilding with usage of specified `OFS`. If you want to know more about start/end of word read [GNU Regexp Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with GNU `awk`:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/[^[:space:]]*([[:alpha:]])/, "\\1","g"); gsub(/\s/,"")} 1' file
GMUCHOS
```

- `gensub()` gets here the characters and `gsub()` removes the spaces between them.

or using `patsplit()`:

```
awk 'n=patsplit($0, a, /[[:alpha:]]\>/) { for (i in a) printf "%s", a[i]} i==n {print ""}' file
GMUCHOS
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach with GNU awk is to use `FPAT` to [split by and keep the content](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html):

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\\S\\>"}
{   s=""
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) s=s $i
    print s
}' file
GMUCHOS
```

Or more tersely and idiomatic:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\\S\\>";OFS=""}{$1=$1}1' file
GMUCHOS
```

(Thanks Daweo for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69705094/298607))

You can also use gensub with:

```
gawk '{print gensub(/\S*(\S\>)\s*/,"\\1","g")}' file
GMUCHOS
```

The advantage here of both is that single letter "words" are handled properly:

```
s2='SINGLE X LETTER Z'

gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\\S\\>";OFS=""}{$1=$1}1' <<< "$s2"
EXRZ

gawk '{print gensub(/\S*(\S\>)\s*/,"\\1","g")}' <<< "$s2"
EXRZ
```

Where the accepted answer and most here *do not*:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) r = r "" substr($i,length($1))} END{print r}' <<< "$s2"
ER       # WRONG

gawk '{print gensub(/([^ ]+)([^ ])( |$)/,"\\2","g")}' <<< "$s2"
EX RZ    # WRONG
```